# Send email from Google Spreasheet is not working

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google Form attached to a spreadsheet.  Everytime the data is submitted via the form into the spreadsheet. Then the spreadsheet should automatically send an email to several individuals but, it's not working.

Here is my code:

```
function myFunction(row) {
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = sheets.getSheets()[0]; // Form Responses 1
  var columnName = sheet.getRange("A1:S1").getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(row);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  var responseObj = {};
  var carId = "";

  for (var i = 2; i < columnName[0].length; i++) {
    var key = columnName[0][i];
    var value = dateFormat(data[0][i],key);
    responseObj[key] = value;
    if(key === "Car ID"){
      carId = value;
    }
  }

  var htmlBodyLoc = doGet(responseObj);

  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: 'person.one@gmail.com,person.two@gmail.com,person.three@gmail.com',
    subject:'Car Inspection - ' + outletId + ' '  + new Date(), 
    htmlBody: htmlBodyLoc,
  });
}
```

I am actually getting an error on this line: **var dataRange = sheet.getRange(row);**

Thanks.

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: If you just run the function, `row` has no value--it is `undefined`. So you are not calling your function properly.

Comment: Here is the error I'm getting: Range not found (file "Code").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 4 ways to call `sheet.getRange()`

`getRange(row, column)`
It is for single cells ranges. 
If you are from VBA, this is the most approximate to worksheet.Cells

`getRange(row, column, numRows)`
This way you can make a range of singles columns and multiple rows, useful sometimes

`getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)`
This is the way to go, programmatically.
E.g `sheet.getRange(1,1,2,2)` will get you the range A1:B2

And finally there is `getRange(a1notation)` which you can use like `sheet.getRange("A1:B2")`

If you are trying to get a single cell of data, maybe you can just change 
`var dataRange = sheet.getRange(row);`
To
`var dataRange = sheet.getRange(row, yourFixedColumn);`
yourFixedColumn being an Integral with index 1 for the column E.g column A = 1
Otherwise you must change the passed argument row to something that complies with the methods listed above.